# TypeError: i.handler.apply is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am working on a cordova android app. I have many pages in the app with lots of buttons e.g to navigate to a new page and get current GPS coordinates of a user.
Everything was working fine but then I did some formatting of the code and noticed that whenever I click a button I get the error

Firefox Browser

> TypeError: i.handler.apply is not a function
>   jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3:28285

DevTools while the app is running on my android phone

> Uncaught TypeError: ((b.event.special[i.origType] || (intermediate value)).handle || i.handler).apply is not a function

Even with this error some of the buttons work (the action is done and error is shown) but some of the buttons don't do anything at all and just give me this error.

I know my app is quite complicated and its difficult for anyone to just say that change this line to that to solve the problem. 
I have tried looking for solutions before writing here but I am not able to understand the error. I am looking for some help in how to debug this problem. I ran the debug mode to fix the error but it's quite confusing for me.
I am using jquery-1.9.1 and jquery-mobile-1.4.5

Please help.